# Testing job queueing in Rails + Minitest + Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, sidekiq, rails-activejob

This my test file:

```
require "test_helper"
include ActiveJob::TestHelper

ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter = :test

describe "A provider requests premium activation", :capybara do
  it "sends an email to SALES_MAIL", js: true do
    login_with_provider(:regular_with_courses, "12345edu")
    click_link('activate-premium-btn')
    assert_enqueued_jobs 1
  end
end
```

`click_link('activate-premium-btn')` makes an AJAX call that executes this action:

```
def process_premium_provider
    provider = Provider.find(params["provider_id"])
    SendInternalInfo.perform_later(provider, "premium_activation_requested")
end
```

I tested manually and it works. However, it seems there is a discrepancy between assert_enqueued_jobs and the jobs actually enqueued.

Running tests, the test is executed, but it fails:

```
A provider requests premium activation::capybara
  test_0001_sends an email to SALES_MAIL                         ERROR (10.22s)
Minitest::Assertion:         1 jobs expected, but 0 were enqueued.
        Expected: 1
          Actual: 0
        test/features/premium_requested_spec.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'


Finished in 10.22569s
1 tests, 1 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

There is something weird however. The test fails but it also throws an ERROR, but it doesn't indicate where the error is.

I'm aware of Sidekiq testing capabilities, but I prefer going the agnostic queue adapter way.

Any ideas of what can be happening?

Thanks.